# If $G$ is simple and $deg_+(v) \ge k\ge 1$ , then there is a simple cycle of at least size $k+1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am going to show you my proof/ and please correct me if wrong:
Begin with some node $v$, and mark it. Follow one of its outgoing edge $(v,w)$ to next unmarked node, and mark it, by doing this repeatedly, at the end we have to re-connect last node at some node to the start one, no way to continue to infinity.

Until this point I proved that it is a cycle, but could someone help me to the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_1v_2\ldots v_m$ be a maximal path (i.e., the $v_i$ are pairwise distinct and consecutive vertices are joined by an edge). Then all the  successors of $v_m$ are among the $v_i$, $1\le i<m$ (because loops are excluded). As at least one of these successors is not among the $k-1$ nodes $v_{m-1},\ldots,v_{m-k+1}$, we obtain a cycle $v_iv_{i+1}\ldots v_mv_i$ with $i\le m-k$ and hence of length $\ge k+1$.

Comment: Danke, 
but please could you explain what you mean by '$v_i$' are pairwise distinct and consecutive vertices are joined by an edge'  , is   '$v_i$' a vertex at some index i or what is it exactly ?

Comment: @TandeeHolwa The first part is essentially just what you did (except that I tried towrite it in a single step): You start with $v_1$ and then follow an outgoing edge to unmarked $v_2$ and so on until you reach $v_m$ and cannot continue because all possible next nodes are already marked. - That the $v_i$ are pairwise distinct corresponds to your marking procedure; that they are joined by an edge corresponds to following an outgoing edge; at any rate, the parentheses merely remind of the definition of *path* ansd should be known. The existence of a *maximal* path follows from finiteness

Comment: see please this graph: 
 
(a)O---->O------>O----->O

^                                |

|--------------------------> (a)O


I do not find a cycle with k+1 ?